# How to find the HTML URL of a Joomla Article?

Tags: url, joomla, article

I created a new article in Joomla in an existing website, but does not know how to find its url. A search online told me that I can find the article with the command http://domainname.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=?? using the specific id of the article. While this worked, what I want to do is to get the HTML URL of that article to use it as a landing page for ad campaigns. How do I find this URL?

Comment: With Joomla, you can't simply have a html landing page associated with the website as Joomla and static are completely different and thus you won't be able to have the same template. You would might be best off designing you're own holding page (index.html) and manually adding the article to it, or using you're Joomla site and disable all modules so it looks more static

Answer (score 2):

Simply, in Administrator Panel > Menus > Create a new menu > add a menu item and configure it to show a Single Article and type the Alias (e.g. offers)

In this way your single article will be reached by adding

Hope this helps